# What remedy exists for the executive branch ignoring laws passed by Congress regarding immigration?

Tags: united-states, immigration, executive

I understand that immigration is the purview of the United States government. What is the remedy when the government fails to enforce its own immigration laws?

Comment: How do you define "failing to enforce immigration laws"?

Comment: Can you be more specific?  Who is failing to do what?  Is the executive branch directing the border services and/or ice not to enforce the laws?  Is congress failing to fund the agencies needed to enforce the laws?  Are the agencies funded, but the executive diverts the funds from the departments which would enforce ? Are the heads of the agencies choosing not to enforce specific laws and the executive lets it pass?  You'll get better answers if you point to a specific concern.

Comment: The buck stops with President.

Comment: This question needs more clarity. What law is being ignored? 
In any case the executive branch has the power of selective prosecution. This applies here too. There is no law that says the executive branch must enforce the law.

Comment: @JohnFx there is such a law, actually, in the form of the faithful execution clause, but the president has a great deal of interpretive discretion in that regard.

Comment: The specific law being ignored is important not only to identify whether there is a duty to enforce it, as other comments have suggested, but also to identify the remedy.  Criminal prosecution might be possible in some cases, whereas immunity would apply in others.  Even in some cases where there is no immunity, the failure to enforce a given law might not constitute a crime.  Civil remedies will only be available if there is an injured party with standing to bring suit and, again, if the defendant is not protected by immunity.

Comment: @phoog The faithful execution clause says **laws** must be faithfully executed. The constitution doesn't specify much about how policing and prosecutions are to be carried out, that comes from laws passed by congress. If those laws say that any crime *must* be prosecuted then the executive would be required by the faithful execution clause to do so. But if the laws allow for discretion as to what is prosecuted, then selective prosecution **is** faithful execution (if it stays within the bounds of discretion permitted by the laws).

Comment: The OP has not clarified what laws are not being enforced, nor the reason they are not.  Need more details and more clarity in defining the question. OP: there is a difference between the E Branch simply not enforcing, and the E Branch not enforcing because the J Branch issues an injunction temporarily halting enforcement, and the L Branch not funding the enforcement. You need to clarify (exactly) what law(s) are not being enforced and who is not and why they aren't, before we can explain what remedies exist.

Comment: @Ben but immigration law doesn't concern only criminal prosecution.  It also includes provisions such as "all aliens seeking admission to the United States shall be inspected by immigration officers."  On its face that doesn't leave any room for discretion.  Which is why questions such as "who is failing to do what" are on point here.

Comment: The ultimate "remedy" is that if a person who isn't a citizen doesn't follow the immigration laws to become a citizen, then they're not a citizen. That means that if an immigration law was not enforced against them at some point, it can be enforced in the future. There are, of course, limits on this principle.

Answer (score 6):

Isn't the fundamental issue that Congress often passes laws giving the executive **powers** rather than giving it **duties**?

What I mean is (highly simplified example) that there might be a set of laws saying that people under certain conditions can be deported, that a particular executive agency can investigate to find such people, that the president can appoint people to manage the agency and decide what its priorities are, etc, etc. The agencies *can* but don't *have* to perform any given possible investigation/prosecution (they cannot possibly perform *every* potential enforcement activity without more resources); the managers can decide what exact activities to prioritise, and the president can appoint and direct the managers (thus ultimately flowing the president's priorities throughout the entire executive). Thus it's entirely possible (and lawful) for the agencies to spend their time and resources doing different activities than you (or Congress) might like.

Most of the President's power is of this form, in my understanding. It's not that the President **inherently** gets to decide whether certain laws are enforced or not. Rather Congress passes laws saying such and such is illegal, and creates an agency with powers of enforcement, and lets the President appoint the people who will (hire other people who will hire more people who will, etc...) determine how those powers are actually used; this ends up giving the President a lot of control over how the law is enforced.

If congress instead chose to write the laws as saying that particular executive agents **must** do such and such activities to enforce the law, the executive branch wouldn't have the option of just deciding not to do those activities.

The remedy (from Congress' point of view) is obvious: if you want executive agents to definitely do something, write laws *requiring* them to do it (and then take the government to court if/when they don't). Don't write laws saying the executive is free to manage enforcement however it likes and then complain when "however it likes" isn't what Congress likes (or when that changes from administration to administration).

Of course, that would require the laws to be far more detailed and fine-grained about exactly who does what in what circumstances to enforce the law. That would mean that detailed plans for enforcement actions are determined through Congressional processes instead of through the managerial processes of the agencies that have to carry them out. I'm not wildly optimistic that that would produce results you would like better.

Comment: Congress has delegated much of its power to enforce immigration laws to the president and to certain cabinet officers.  Much of that does indeed take the form of duties imposed on the executive.  The "general provisions" chapter of the Immigration and Nationality Act (INA) establishes "powers and duties" of various cabinet officers (and, by extension, their departments).  See https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/8/chapter-12/subchapter-I

Comment: While much of the INA establishes requirements related to foreigners, as you note, it's hard to escape the conclusion that there is an executive duty, for example, to establish immigration inspectors at ports of entry, to issue visas to certain classes of aliens, to inspect them according to the requirements laid out in the INA, and to refuse entry if they are inadmissible. On the other hand, "deportable aliens ... shall, upon the order of the Attorney General, be removed," but nothing compels the issue of such an order: https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/8/1227

Comment: @phoog Yes, I'm dramatically over-simplifying. Real laws of course grant powers *and* duties, in varying mixes. But the core point is that where the executive has freedom to choose not to enforce laws in certain cases, that freedom came from Congress. If Congress thinks that is a problem, Congress can change the law to reduce the executive's freedom.

Answer (score 1):

This question can be broken into two parts, since the "executive branch" consists of the political layer (i.e. The presidency and its subordinate political appointees) and the bureaucratic layer (i.e. non-political civil servants).

At the bureaucratic layer, civil servants are expected to perform adminsitrative duties strictly according to law. If they break the law there will be consequences, either they lose their job or get prosecuted if the offense is severe.

At the political layer, the President of Untied States and his/her appointees enjoy certain degree of immunity - it's much harder to hold them accountable through ordinary judicial system. In this instance, it is incumbent on Congress to hold them politically accountable, with the ultimate instrument being impeachment of the President.

It should be noted that the bureaucratic and political layer rely on each other to function. For instance, even if the political layer goes nuts and wants to break all the laws, they still cannot carry out their policy if the civil service refuses to implement their law breaking policies. Ideally, a well functioning civil service is like an impartial computer telling the user they cannot do something that the code does not allow.

Hope this is clear.